# Open multiple instances(=windows) of same .nb?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, system

Is it possible to open multiple instances of the same .nb (on local disk)?

First, open `c:\test1\test1.nb`.
After that, can you open another instance(=window) of `c:\test1\test1.nb` ?

I tried to find related option in global setting of option inspectors, but couldn't.

Note that this question is not about creating a dynamic, where editing one notebook causes the other notebook to be edited in the same way, in real time.
This question has nothing to do with dynamics.

Comment: I've done it with different mathematica versions, but not with the same one

Comment: Thank you, you are going through the same difficulties!

Comment: The obvious fix is to copy the file and edit that.  But it's a bit clunky.

Comment: On Linux, I can launch two instances of Mathematica and open the same file in each.

Comment: There seems to be no way to **truly** open two windows for the same file.